# Write a function that given a List and a pattern returns the matching elements

Tags: java, string

List of camel case Strings:
['HelloMars', 'HelloWorld', 'HelloWorldMars', 'HiHo']

Test cases:

- H -> [HelloMars, HelloWorld, HelloWorldMars, HiHo]
- HW -> [HelloWorld, HelloWorldMars]
- Ho -> []
- HeWorM -> [HelloWorldMars]

here is what i tried out:

```
private static List<String> findMatchingCamel(String patter){
    List<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> myData=Arrays.asList("HelloMars","HelloWorld","HelloWorldMars","HiHo");

    String[] upperCasePattern=splitBasedOnUpperCaseLetter(patter);
    for(String str1:myData){
        boolean found=true;
        for(String s:upperCasePattern){
            if(str1.indexOf(s)==-1)
            {
                found=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found)
            result.add(str1);
    }
    return result;
}

private static String[] splitBasedOnUpperCaseLetter(String str){
    String[] result=str.split("(?=[A-Z])");
    return result;
}
```

my function is not working on cases for example on when the pattern is Ho it is returning HiHo. How can i improve it; fix the bug and also return result in the minimum time as possible?

Comment: try using regex and replace your input string putting `.*` before each uppercase letter (except the first one), and in the end of the string... In your example, "H.*", "H.*W.*", "Ho.*" and "He.*Wor.*M.*"

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the word is in the order of your data, so

```
private static List<String> findMatchingCamel(String patter){
    List<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
    // Split the data on UpperCase too
    List<String[]> myData=Arrays.asList(
        splitBasedOnUpperCaseLetter("HelloMars"),
        splitBasedOnUpperCaseLetter("HelloWorld"),
        splitBasedOnUpperCaseLetter("HelloWorldMars"),
        splitBasedOnUpperCaseLetter("HiHo")
    );

    String[] upperCasePattern = splitBasedOnUpperCaseLetter(patter);
    for(String[] str1:myData){
        boolean valid = true;
        if(upperCasePattern.length() <= str1.length())
            // For the UpperCase splits length
            for(int i=0; i<upperCasePattern.length(); i++){
                // If string do not match the start of the data
                if(!upperCasePattern[i].equals(str1[i].substring(0,upperCasePattern[i].length())){
                    // Go on the next data
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(valid)
                result.add(str1.toString());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: am getting Cannot invoke join() on the array type String[] at `result.add(str1.join());`

Comment: `result.add(str1.toString());` just concatenate the strings.

Comment: `if(!upperCasePattern[i].equals(str1[i].substring(0,upperCasePattern[i].length())))` line is throwing java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2 when pattern is 'Ho'

Answer (score 0):

In the following condition you check if the pattern exist in the string

```
for(String s:upperCasePattern){
        if(str1.indexOf(s)==-1)
        {
            found=false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

But the patter should be in the given sequence given. What you can do is that you can split each string in the myData similar to pattern. Then try to match both string array.If the pattern exist in the myData's splitted string array for the same index as upperCasePattern. Code might look like this:

```
for(String str1:myData){

    String[] upperCaseMyData = splitBasedOnUpperCaseLetter(str1);

    boolean found=true;int length = 0;

    if(upperCaseMyData.length<upperCasePatter.length)
    {
        length = upperCaseMyData.length;
    }
    else
    {
        length = upperCasePatter.length;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(upperCaseMyData[i].indexOf(upperCasePatter[i])==-1)
        {
            found=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found)
        result.add(str1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but its not working on the test cases provided